# Which caching mode does Stratis-storage use? writeback or writethrough?

Tags: cache, storage

Having a large HDD and a small SSD makes me tempted to use Stratis for my /home because currently I can't recognize my manually LVM cached partition scheme anymore.

According to [Linuxsysadmins: Manage Stratis layered storage](https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/manage-stratis-layered-storage/), caching mode should be configurable but `stratis pool init-cache -h`'s result doesn't give any information:

```
usage: stratis pool init-cache [-h] pool_name blockdevs [blockdevs ...]

positional arguments:
  pool_name   Name of the pool for which to initialize the cache
  blockdevs   Initialize the pool cache using these block devs

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Bcache seems viable but in Arch Linux, it must be installed from AUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get some clarity on the Stratis GitHub project page and it does appear that write-through cache is currently the default and only option. I parsed the majority of the stratisd and stratis-cli code and found no reference to allowing configuration arguments for write cache mode. I'm sure those options will come in time.

https://github.com/stratis-storage/project/discussions/529#discussioncomment-3815035